# Epson NX430 colors print misaligned

Tags: printing, epson

My Epson NX430 works in Windows, but on Linux ( 14.04 ), the colors are misaligned.

It seems that Epson send you to some weird site for Linux drivers:
http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule
Hopefully not Russian hackers...

I tried installing the latest version, it did not work.
"Package operation failed" window pops up, in the Software Center: "failed to satisfy all dependencies (broken cache)" (

I am trying to reinstall:
"New software can't be installed, because there is a problem with the software currently installed.  Do you want to repair this problem?"  I say YES, but that seems to get me in a loop.

Here is the last of the "Details":

Preparing to unpack .../epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb ...

```
Unpacking epson-inkjet-printer-escpr (1.6.0-1lsb3.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:
 epson-inkjet-printer-escpr depends on lsb (>= 3.2).

dpkg: error processing package epson-inkjet-printer-escpr (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
```

Here is somewhere else that someone asked this, from 2013, but it was not answered.

http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=132074

If you need additional information, let me know

Comment: Is your system 32-bit?

Answer (score 0):

After you installed the Epson deb packages, run

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

All dependencies will be installed and the driver will be installed too.

After you install the deb package you will need to install new printer again with the new driver.